# PHP loop to array to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have this code to fetch all data from database

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){                          
$therow1 = $row['r1'];
$therow2 = $row['r2'];
$therow3 = $row['r3'];//get
$therow4 = $row['r4'];//get

}
```

How can I get the `$therow3` and `$therow3` as an array then pass it on javascript as array.

The expected output in javascript array would be:
**$the_array**

```
 [
    [-33.890542, 151.274856],
    [-33.923036, 151.259052],
    [-34.028249, 151.157507],
    [-33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
    [-33.950198, 151.259302]
    ];
```

Then I will use this array in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = $the_array;

</script>
```

Comment: $the_array[$therow3] = $row['r3'];

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

**PHP:**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){                          
    $therow1 = $row['r1'];
    $therow2 = $row['r2'];
    $therow3 = $row['r3'];//get
    $therow4 = $row['r4'];//get
    $the_array[] = [$therow3, $therow4];
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($the_array); ?>');

</script>
```

Comment: This just give me ["1","20","10","11","10","120"] , should be [[1,20],[10,11],[10,120]]

Answer (score 0):

To send an array in a format JavaScript understands, you need to encode it as JSON in PHP, then decode it in the Javascript

```
<?php
    $the_array = json_encode([
        $row['r3'], $row['r4']
    ]);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = JSON.parse('<?=$the_array?>');
</script>
```